# How to disable PAE feature of kernel, after installation?

Tags: centos, kernel, rhel, kernel-modules, pae

I am using RHEL 5.3(x86) as a base platform for my development purpose.My machine's spec is as follows:

```
Intel, Core-i3 Processor @ 2.5GHz
4GB RAM
```

Problem  is whenever I am attempting to install the kernel(2.6.18), it is being installed as PAE feature enabled kernel. This is restricting me from loading some pre-compiled kernel.Whenever I am issuing

```
insmod module_name
```

it is giving error, saying about the existence of incompatibility issues.

I did a lot of browsing. They are saying that the PAE support is default feature, in RHEL 5.3(x86).
But didnt find any clue how to  disable it, to run the module successfully

Comment: You would need to install a kernel that doesn't have PAE enabled.

Comment: I believe you'll need to recompile your own version of the Kernel w/ that feature disabled if you really want it w/o.